# Why are they so different, Dept of Transportation (US) and Dept for Transport (UK)?

Tags: word-choice

These two are the government agencies of the same function. But out of the total three words that make up the phrase, there are two that are different, especially the preposition words "of" and "for". I don't think lingusitic habits of two countries are a sound answer.

Comment: "linguistic habits of two countries" *is* the answer, though. Why don't you think it's sound? "Dept for <anything>" sounds very strange in the US, as does "transport" to mean "transportation." I assume the opposite is true in the UK.

Comment: Not that there _needs_ to be a reason for analogous agencies in different jurisdictions to have similar but distinct names. But @Esther is right, both these differences happen to be regional.

Comment: @Esther So there is no problem of grammar? Do you mean that "of" and "for" could be interchangable?Being not a native speaker, I have to make sure what is behind this, or I might have my score deducted in a test.

Comment: @JamesK Please don't politicize this language problem. I am a decent learner of English language, though I don't mind learning more about the world. And what is more, for curiosity, can you give some examples of the Mao you said that names were changed as he wished to prove your point?

Answer (score 3):

We devious Brits can't even stick to our own habits! We have the Department **of** Health and Social Care, and the **Ministries of** Justice and Defence (note pesky Brit spelling again!). Trying to find a reason might be a thankless task. It might be that a Department *for* something sounds like the agency is actively promoting a good thing (e.g. education, transport, international trade) rather than just supervising and regulating it, but that's just my guess.

"Do you mean that "of" and "for" could be interchangeable?" - Proper names including the names of government agencies cannot be changed in that way without committing an error.

Comment: And the Department for Transport used to be the Ministry of Transport! UK government departments keep changing their style of name - most inconvenient for library cataloguers, among others.

Comment: @KateBunting - some older and/or more cynical Civil Servants call it 're-arranging the deckchairs on the Titanic'. Plum jobs at a higher grade for 'Change Managers' who are 'skilled at delivering change at pace', etc.

Comment: @KateBunting and of course MoT tests are named after the Ministry of Transport, even though these days they are administered by the Dept of Transport.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - -when I was a boy people called the flashing orange lights at zebra crossings 'Belisha beacons' after Mr  Hore-Belisha, minister of transport in 1938.

Comment: Isn't that still their official name?